# How to properly use HOC with Hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-hoc

**What is the best way to use HOC if I need to get data from a hook?**

I have two options:

1. Pass the received data from the hook as a parameter to the HOC

HOC:

```
export const withAuth = (
  isAuth: boolean,
  {
    ComponentForAuthorized,
    ComponentForUnauthorized,
  }: {
    ComponentForAuthorized: () => JSX.Element;
    ComponentForUnauthorized: () => JSX.Element;
  }
) => {
  const WrappedComponent = (props: any) => {
    if (isAuth) return <ComponentForAuthorized {...props} />;
    else return <ComponentForUnauthorized {...props} />;
  };

  return WrappedComponent;
};
```

And use like this:

```
export const Sidebar = () => {
  const { token } = useJWT();
  const AccountComponent = withAuth(Boolean(token), {
    ComponentForAuthorized: AccountBlock,
    ComponentForUnauthorized: LoginButton,
  });

  return (
      <AccountComponent />
  );
};
```

2. Call hook in HOC

HOC:

```
export const withAuth =
  (
    ComponentForAuthorized: () => JSX.Element,
    ComponentForUnauthorized: () => JSX.Element
  ) =>
  (props: any) => {
    const { token } = useJWT();

    const WrappedComponent = () => {
      if (Boolean(token)) return <ComponentForAuthorized {...props} />;
      else return <ComponentForUnauthorized {...props} />;
    };

    return WrappedComponent();
  };
```

Are there any recommendations or best practices?

Answer (score 1):

Best practice is to avoid using HOCs to wrap components and instead rewrite the HOC functionality as custom hooks and import those into the components.

https://kentcdodds.com/chats/01/03/realigning-your-model-of-react-after-hooks-with-dan-abramov

Answer (score 0):

if you must use HOC.

> Pass the received data from the hook as a parameter to the HOC

It May be easy to Test with [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)

**But** you should probably use a custom hook as [Luke Storry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13892264/luke-storry) suggested.